# How to access base windows form class variable or function which is private from child form class (c#)

Tags: c#

I am writing a windows form application in c#. I changed my design to have menus. I have base class and several child class for each menu item. My problem is in my base class i am accessing a GUI element and storing its value in a public variable. now i want to access this from my child class.

```
public partial class x: Form

{
 # calling this public method from child class to to get the variable value 
      public string Getlogpath()
           {
               Console.WriteLine(this.logpath);
               return logsdirectory.Text;
           }
     private void reportFromLogsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                       
               Form2 child1 = new Form2();                  
               this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade);                        
               child1.Show();            

          }
 public void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
           fbd.SelectedPath = (@"\\comprion02\ots\SHARED\T\COMPRION SIMfony\Log-Files");
           fbd.ShowDialog();
           logsdirectory.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
           logpath = logsdirectory.Text;
           # this print i get value i need
           Console.WriteLine(logpath);
       }
}

#child form class

 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data;
            x obj = new x();           
            data = obj.Getlogpath();

           #got nothing for this print
           Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
 }
```

could someone help me with this.

Comment: Is the variable *actually* public or private? Your code doesn't declare *any* instance variables, and your question title and body disagree. I would personally avoid public variables anyway, exposing things via properties if absolutely necessary...

Comment: That's not a child class.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(x)...?? Are you sure here ?? I mean, It should be like Console.WriteLine(data).. !! Dont you think so... x is class as it seems from the code... And neither the inheritance seems correct..!!

Comment: Hi, variable is public.

Comment: sorry for that its data inside `console.writeline()`

Comment: Winforms is traditionally where programmers first learn about object oriented programming and what the *new* operator really means.  Same here, you are creating a *new* instance of the form.  One that has an "logpath" variable that isn't assigned.  Also consider what happens when the user clicks "button1" but hasn't yet clicked the "browse" button.  Learning OOP through trail and error produces a *lot* of error.  There are *many* books and classes that can help you avoid these pains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `Console.WriteLine(Form.Getlogpath());` instead of `Console.WriteLine(x);`

Or create object of your `Form` class instead of `X` class:

```
           Form obj = new Form();
           Console.WriteLine(obj.Getlogpath());
```

Comment: What do you get by using this? any exception?

Comment: Error: `'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Getlogpath'`

Comment: Create object of your `Form` class, instead of `X` class.

Comment: `Form obj = new Form();  `
`Console.WriteLine(obj.Getlogpath());` `'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Getlogpath' and no extension method 'Getlogpath' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I get this error: `'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Getlogpath' and no extension method 'Getlogpath' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Change your class name from `Form` to something else. It is referencing to the `Form` class of `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the keyword protected instead of private or public. See more here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.71).aspx